# how to remove unnecessary parentheses?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, header-footer, biber, biblatex-chicago

Here is my full code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@article{Chua1999,
author = {Chua},
title = {A title},
journal = {A Journal},
year = {1999},
}\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate-trad]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{foo}  ...
    \caption[Caption for LOF]{Real caption\protect\footnotemark}
  \end{figure}
\footnotetext{\footfullcite{Chua1999}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have a problem with this command:

```
\footnotetext{\footfullcite{Chua1999}}
```

I added \footfullcite command inside \footnotetext because i wanted to add figure's caption reference in the footnote but in the output i got unnecessary parentheses as i mentioned in the screenshot by red arrows.

I wanted to know how can i remove this unnecessary parentheses here.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just want `\fullcite`. The command `\footfullcite` is for a footnote full citation in text and not inside `\footnote` (or `\footnotetext`).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{Chua1999,
  author = {Chua},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate-trad]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setlength{\textheight}{4.5cm} % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\caption[Caption for LOF]{Real caption\protect\footnotemark}

\end{figure}
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Chua1999}}

%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]